# How do I access the query string in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-show

I have an ng-repeat that works fine, until I try to put a limitation on it.

This works fine:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="main-content" ng-controller="HomeController">

<div class="attorney" ng-repeat="attorney in attorneys">
   {{attorney.name}} 
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

It spits out the lawyers' names. But when I try to add a condition into it:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="main-content" ng-controller="HomeController">

<div class="attorney" ng-repeat="attorney in attorneys" ng-show="attorney.id == $location.search().id">
   {{attorney.name}} 
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

It doesn't display anything. I'm assuming I'm doing that ng-show wrong, but I can't seem to find how to properly do it.

Thanks!

Comment: may be attorney.id == $location.search().id results in false always?

Comment: Have you attached `$location` to a `$location` property on the scope. Bindings are always evaluated in context of scope.

Comment: BTW, instead of looping over all the lawyers and hiding them all except the one with the correct ID, the controller should expose THE lawyer to display on the scope, and the view should display it, without looping.

Comment: These two both look promising, but I'm not sure how to do either of them. Could you please provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: You'd first have to try it out yourself, and post your best attempt if you're stuck.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if you mean only pulling the one record out of the JSON? Does that make sense? I'd have to hit the controller over and over again every time someone clicks on a different bio. EDIT: I just found out about ng-if. Maybe that's what you mean. I'll try that out.